# How can I resolve the error SQLPS failed to initialize?ows

Tags: sql-server, powershell-3.0, sqlps

Environment:
Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
SQL Server 2008 R2

Installed the Microsoft Windows Management Framework 3.0 plus it's prerequisites to get Powershell 3.0

On server Powershell prompt I get this:
PS C:\Users\macfarmw> sqlps
SQLPS failed to initialize: Could not load type 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand' from assembly 'Micr
osoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
PS C:\Users\macfarmw>

Is my installation of Powershell 3.0 breaking the SQLPS utility? Can I resolve this can keep Powershell 3.0?

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

SQLPS require PS2 so PS3 is also good.

Get the list of loaded assembiles on this machine and compare with list from working machine.

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname
```

That way you should find the difference and the source of the problem...